# Printing value along with it's data type

Tags: go

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main() {
    anInt := 1234
    fmt.Printf("Data Type:", "%T\n", anInt, "Value is:", anInt)
}
```

Ouput:

```
Data Type:%!(EXTRA string=%T
, int=1234, string=Value is:, int=1234)
```

But Expected Output:

```
Data Type: int, Value is: 1234
```

I have tried using import reflect still not the expected result

Data Type:%!(EXTRA *reflect.rtype=int, string=Value is:, int=1234)

Answer (score 1):

> [Package fmt](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/)
>
> ```
> import "fmt"
> ```
>
> [func Printf](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Print)
>
> ```
> func Printf(format string, a ...interface{}) (n int, err error)
> ```
>
> Printf formats according to a format specifier and writes to standard
>   output. It returns the number of bytes written and any write error
>   encountered.

---

It's a single format string. For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    anInt := 1234
    fmt.Printf("Data Type: %T\nValue is: %v\n", anInt, anInt)
    // or, concise version
    fmt.Printf("Data Type: %[1]T\nValue is: %[1]v\n", anInt)
}
```

Output:

```
Data Type: int
Value is: 1234
Data Type: int
Value is: 1234
```

Comment: Also, in the format string argument index can be used to pass variable only once: `fmt.Printf("Data Type: %T\nValue is: %[1]v", anInt)`